# Correct syntax to clear invalid Marketing Cloud Connect OAuth Tokens?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am currently experiencing an issue with individual email results syncing from from marketing cloud to sales cloud from a child business unit (IER's from the parent business unit are syncing just fine).  I have a case in with support (but that is slow going so I'd thought I'd check in here too), and I was referred to the following article to clear invalid tokens:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_clear_invalid_tokens.htm&type=5

The syntax provided (pasted below) does not seem to be correct, as I could not get it to execute after a number of iterations.  I eventually found a knowledge article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1) that had a slightly different version.

Code that would not run (I tried many different versions of this):

```
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER'); 
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|<Default MID >');
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|<MID 2>');
```

Code that did run:

```
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('UserId', TRUE);
```

The second version definitely seemed to work to clear the tokens at the parent level, however, I am still experiencing issues with the child business units.  I am wondering if I need to also clear the tokens in the child business units (as indicated in the first article), but I cannot figure out how to do it.  Does anyone know the proper syntax to clear the tokens for the other business units? Or have any other thoughts/recommendations for this particular issue, I'd welcome them.

Answer (score 1):

I often use below query for the clearance of OAuth tokens for Marketing cloud connect. Before this you have to disconnect the Salesforce Integration in Marketing cloud --> Email Studio--> Salesforce Integration. Based on how many business unit is connected with Salesforce run the query one bye one in the Developer Console of Salesforce (Debug.

```
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('Use the User ID’s of the System(tracking) user 
(System User or API User'); 
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('Use the User ID’s of the System(tracking) user 
(System User or API User| Use the MID’s of the Marketing Cloud Business Unit); 
Then Run 
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER'); 
et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|MID); 
Ex:- 
      et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('005o000000XXXXXXXX');
      et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('005o000000XXXXXXXX|64XXXXX');
      et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER');
      et4ae5.SupportUtilities.deleteUserTokens('APIUSER|64XXXXX');
```

Note : You need to know how many Business Unit are connected with that System User/API User.